# How to fix this implicitly convert error in c# with if-else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, implicit-conversion

Can you help me with this? I'm getting this error in my code:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'

I've searched on the internet to fix this and saw stackoverflow  questions still not fixed. The code is

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("How are you?");
      
      string choice = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //Error in this line
      
      if (choice == "Fine" || choice == "Good" || choice == "doing well")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("It's great to know that you're" + choice);
      }
      
      else if (choice == "bad" || choice == "not good" || choice == "not so well")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("What happened? Why" + choice + "?");
      }
            
    }
  }
}
```

A question in stackoverflow recommended me to use `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse` before `ReadLine`.  Used so but still errors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

```
string choice = bool.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

There is seemingly no need to convert a `string` to a `bool`, back to a `string` here.

You are obviously comparing the `string` from the input against choices.

```
if (choice == "Fine" || choice == "Good" || choice == "doing well")
```

Choice just needs to be a `string`, there is no need for a `bool` here..

Instead just use ***the*** `string`

```
string choice = Console.ReadLine();

if (choice == "Fine" || choice == "Good" || choice == "doing well")
```

---

You would use [`bool.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse?view=net-5.0) if someone entered "true" or "false" and you wanted to convert that string input to a `bool`.

> Converts the specified span representation of a logical value to its
> Boolean equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ah! it's fixed. Now i can write my program.  Can you suggest me something from where i can learn complete c#? The website i'm now following is **W3Schools" .  But i think it doesn’t contain all of c#. In my code editor i see lots of codes. But those code's example/description is not in w3schools.

Comment: @AcpSiam, there is no real one stop shop. However, there is a lot of good content on youtube and many blogs. You can also keep asking questions here. Just make sure you keep them at a good quality, also the C# documentation is really good, all you do is search in google with C# and what you want to do. Good luck